# Exchange versions mixed vs native mode?

Tags: exchange

I'm just trying to confirm that the following statements are correct:

Exchange 2003 had mixed/native modes:
  Mixed kept the system backwards compatible with Exchange 5.5 (or earlier).
  Native mode lost that compatibility, but would work with 2000+.

Exchange 2007 & 2010 have no concept of Mixed/Native modes and are not compatible with Exchange 5.5 (or earlier).

To my knowledge these statements are correct. If I am wrong could someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much are right. 2007 was a significant step forward architecturally. Coexistence with the old systems was not really an option.